# Warning C4101 unreferenced local variable

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

```
void func(char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
.....lots of code here not using param
}
```

Getting error for compilation and I don't want warning even in code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an "Unreferenced Local Variable" warning? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895020/why-do-i-get-an-unreferenced-local-variable-warning-c)

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It doesn't help in my case, I think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++17 we have the [`maybe_unused` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) to suppress warnings on unused entities:

```
void func([[maybe_unused]] char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. If the `_XYZ_` is **NOT** defined the the variable `param` is not used in the function and the compiler issue a waning that can be translated to:

Translated from compilerian:

> My friend you asked me for a piece of memory named `param` but you are
>   not using it. Are you sure this is intended?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++17's `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute, you can use compiler-specific commands.

In MSVC, you can do this:

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4101)
void func(char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
#pragma warning(pop)
```

In Borland/Embarcadero, you can do this:

```cpp
#pragma argsused
void func(char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
```

In GCC, you can use one of these:

```cpp
void func(__attribute__((unused)) char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
```

```cpp
void func(__unused char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
```

```cpp
void func([[gnu::unused]] char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#endif
}
```

Or, you could simply reference the parameter without using any compiler-specific tricks:

```cpp
void func(char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
.....somecode here using param
#else
(void)param;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about: `static_cast<void>(param);`

Use same method also used to [discard result marked `[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard):

> other than a cast to void, the compiler is encouraged to issue a
> warning.

```
[[nodiscard]] bool is_good_idea();

void func(char * param)
{
#ifdef _XYZ_
  .....somecode here using param
#else
  // suppress warning:
  static_cast<void>(param);
#endif

  // also valid:
  static_cast<void>(is_good_idea());
}
```

Compiler won't produce any additional instructions :)

Comment: Actually, you have used parameter in both the paths So the compiler will not generate a warning.

Comment: Yes, answering your specific question: `I don't want warning`.

Comment: But the shown example, where I don't it needs to be considered as well. :)

Comment: You must express the "intent" that variable is left unused and that compiler doesn't need to remind you about it. Its yes/no answer to the question did you forget about "this" variable. Do not apply some sneaky solution to hide this intent, other devs will curse you for it.

Comment: Most of the above answers might help with multiple solutions to the problem.